# Is SSAS a semantic layer?

Tags: ssas

I can't seem to find a source which defines semantic layer tools and I would like to if strictly speaking SSAS is a semantic layer, a tool used to create one or how it would be defined?

Comment: Semantic layer is not a tightly defined concept.  We can broadly define a semantic layer as an architectural construct designed to facilitate reporting by incorporating report-specific calculations, presentation or metric/filtering logic as opposed to data transformation or scrubbing.  A semantic layer could be implemented in cubes - i.e. logic within the cubes or DSVs, although it's not only way to do it.

Comment: @ConcernedOfTunbridgeWells So essentially SSAS tabular model is a semantic layer?

Comment: It is a physical OLAP server, but you can implement a semantic layer with tabular model cubes (i.e. you can put final metric definitions, calculations and business rules in the cube)